# Schengen 2 entry with for 10 days

Tags: schengen

If I get a 10 day Schengen visa with 2 entries or MULT can I stay 10 days in each visit or the total duration of my Schengen stay is limited to 10 days. I ask this as I want to visit UK but return home from a Schengen country to save on airfare cost.

Comment: Just want to mention your Schengen visa is useless in the UK

Comment: 10 days = 10 days. If they wanted you to use 10 days on each visit, your Schengen would be for 20 days.  So your total time in Schengen must be <= 10 days.

Comment: Didn't you explain your plans when applying for the visa?

Comment: Perfect. And so nothing to worry.

Answer (score 1):

The validity of the visa is for the whole stay, regardless of how many times you enter. That means a multiple entry Schengen visa valid for 10 days is valid for a trip totaling 10 days where you can enter the area multiple times before it's expired.

Comment: yes yes .You are right

Comment: It seems that the trip's total may be more than 10 days; one could spend 5 days in Schengen, then 5 days outside Schengen, then 5 more days in Schengen.  No?

Comment: @phoog sure but he's asking about the duration of the Schengen stay